# Serve single file Angular app from S3 with nginx

Tags: angularjs, nginx, amazon-s3

I have an Angular app that consists of a single index.html file. The only others files are main.css and some image assets. I've already rediscovered there is no way to use S3 web hosting to serve it so I'm trying to set up nginx as a proxy. I have done this before but it was years ago and it wasn't with an Angular app and HTML5 push state. Here is the current nginx config server block I have.

```
server {
    server_name foo.com;

    set $s3_bucket        'foo.com.s3.amazonaws.com';

    proxy_http_version     1.1;
    proxy_set_header       Host $s3_bucket;
    proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
    proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
    proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
    proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
    proxy_ignore_headers   "Set-Cookie";
    proxy_buffering        off;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;

    resolver               172.16.0.23 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout       10s;

    location ~* ^/(assets|styles)/(.*) {
        set $url_full         '$1/$2';
        proxy_pass             http://$s3_bucket/live/$url_full;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^ /live/index.html break;
        proxy_pass http://$s3_bucket;
    }
}
```

I don't assume anything with this config. It could all be completely wrong.

It does "work". I can go to foo.com and the site serves and I can navigate and it all work wonders. But it won't load any URL that is not /. All other redirect to / and that is a problem.

What am I doing wrong? All help appreciated.